# Meteor Collection exists in Mongo but returns ReferenceError in browser console

Tags: mongodb, meteor, collections, coffeescript, referenceerror

I'm setting up a new Meteor project and am having trouble working with collections on the client side. Right now what I'm building is an administrative page where a user can maintain a list of schools.

Running `meteor mongo` and `db.schools.find()` in Terminal returns a BSON object just as I would expect, however when I enter "Schools" in the Chrome console it returns `Uncaught ReferenceError: Schools is not defined` which is a bummer.

My project architecture (simplified to the bits that reference the School collection) is as follows:

```
client/
  layouts/
    admin/
      schools.coffee
      schools.jade
  lib/
    subscriptions.coffee
lib/
  collections.coffee
server/
  lib/
    publications.coffee
```

The contents of each of these files (in the desirable load order) is:

1) **lib/collections.coffee**

```
 1| Schools = new Mongo.Collection('schools')
```

2) **server/lib/publications.coffee**

```
 1| Meteor.publish('schools'), ->
 2|   Schools.find()
```

3) **client/lib/subscriptions.coffee**

```
 1| Meteor.subscribe('schools')
```

4) **client/layouts/admin/schools.coffee**

```
76| Template.admin_schools.helpers
77|   schools: ->
78|     Schools.find()
79|   numSchools: ->
80|     Schools.find().count()
81|   hasSchools: ->
82|     Schools.find().count() > 0
```

5) **client/layouts/admin/schools.jade**

```
 4| h2.admin__header Schools
 5|   span.admin__record-count {{numSchools}} entries
...
22| table.admin__list
23|   if hasSchools
24|     each schools
25|       tr.admin__list-item
26|         td #{name}
```

*I also have a form for new collection entries which calls `Schools.insert`, but the error there is the same.*

When the page loads, I get the following error (likely because it is called first):

```
debug.js:41 Exception in template helper: ReferenceError: Schools is not defined
at Object.Template.admin_schools.helpers.numSchools
```

Those two errors, combined with the fact that I know there exists an entry in the collection, leads me to believe that the issue lies with the client side's awareness of the existence of the collection.

This discrepancy might possibly be due to load order (I am pretty sure I accounted for that by putting the important files in `lib/` directories, though I would love a second opinion), or maybe due to a spelling/syntax mistake (though the absence of compile errors is puzzling). Maybe something completely different!

Thank you very much for your time and assistance, they are much appreciated.

Comment: In the documentation here http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/structuringyourapp, check for the "File Load Order" section which says client/lib will be loaded before /lib. An approach that worked for us is to add collections in a package and export them (Packages will be loaded first).

Comment: A simple test would be to have a lib folder inside lib folder at deepest level than other folders. Something like /lib/someFolder/lib/collections.coffee. If this works then it is the deepest lib folder that will be loaded first.

Comment: @Kishor I now have `lib/one/two/lib/collections.coffee` (4 deep), `lib/one/two/lib/permissions.coffee` (4 deep), `server/one/lib/publications.coffee` (3 deep), and `client/lib/subscriptions.coffee` (2 deep) and regretably I'm still getting the same error on page load as before. I'll definitely look into the packaging option, though that seems a bit hackier than I'd like. Unless I'm missing something, shouldn't this be a lot easier to negotiate if the purpose of the root `lib/` directory is to prep things for both client and server sides?

Comment: I see. That is strange. Yes, it should be quite straight forward. Based on your error client/layouts/admin/schools.coffee is loading before lib/collections.coffee, which shouldn't be the case.

Comment: I just found another clue, perhaps. In the Terminal that's running Meteor, when I refresh Chrome I see the following error: `Exception from sub schools id gtaJGhoSz3yMT54hc RefrenceError: Schools is not defined at [object Object]._handler (server/one/lib/publications.coffee:2:3)` so perhaps the error is just as much on the server side as it is on the client, further supporting the hypothesis that the `lib/.../collections.coffee` is getting loaded late.

Comment: Problem might be subscribing to collections when app starts. Instead of subscribing to `schools` in 'client/lib/subscriptions.coffee' you should do it in the `Template.admin_schools.onCreated` function of 'client/layouts/admin/schools.coffee'. You can then remove the publications out of lib folder as well.

Comment: The `Meteor.subscribe('schools')` call is now in that `onCreated` function and `server/one/lib/publications.coffee` has been removed. When that didn't work I also put the `lib/.../collections.coffee` line into a `Meteor.startup` function but no dice there either. This is tricky! Thank you so much for your help. I'll keep poking around and see what happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that because this is CoffeeScript, placing an `@` before `Schools = new Mongo.Collection('schools')` in `lib/collections.coffee` makes Schools a global variable, thereby solving the problem! Pretty simple fix in the end :)

Special thanks to [Kishor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3238986/kishor) for helping troubleshoot.

Comment: Nice to know that issue is resolved. Accept this is an answer, so that it will not only help others but also increase your own reputation points, I think. :)

Answer (score -1):

Have you checked your subscriptions on created?

Comment: Your answer is not an answer, it is a question. So it might be better to comment on the question. :)